# Four memory modules wont work

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory

I decided to up my memory to 32GB and installed an additional 16 with the 16 that was already present.  The system wouldn't boot but I tried running with only the new modules and it did.  The only configuration that would not work was when I had a module in the slot next to the processor.  With three in it boots but I get a bsod after a while.  I know that all modules are good but I am wondering if the board has a failure or if there is some setting that I am not aware of that is responsible.  I have a B450 Aorus Elite with a Ryzen 7 2700 processor running Windows 7.
 Thanks to jluizsouzadev for the help.  I didn't want to extend discussion but I have flashed and I still can't use all for sticks.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: First, try to boot your OS with some memory in way succefull, when managed it, then try to upgrade your BIOS. Which the **model and capacity of all the memories**? Are you trying to upgrade the BIOS to the **F51 version**, right?

Comment: Yes, but I got an error when trying to flash.  Is it necessary to flash from Command Prompt?  Or should I use the Q-Flash option in BIOS?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  will check the manual then try it out.

Comment: Use the Q-Flash option. [It's example of a similar BIOS upgrade process useful to show how to do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXhKqOKesFA)

Comment: I recommend you to upgrade your OS to Windows 10 for [security reasons](https://www.core.co.uk/blog/blog/10-security-reasons-upgrade-windows-10) and so on after upgrade your BIOS succesfully

Comment: Thanks jluizsouzadev.  I do have Windows 10 on a partition but I can't give up 7 just yet.  It was a scary operation but I flashed and will try to install the RAM now.  Thanks a lot for your help.